# Problems with isdigit()

Tags: python, while-loop, integer, flags, digits

To start off, I am very new to coding, and there is probably a lot I could have done better with my code.  My main problem is that whenever I make the first element of my list a non-digit, my while loop catches it, allows me to change the element to a digit, but isdigit() still flags it as False, and it loops again.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
def matrix_maker():
        count = 1
        validInteger = False
        pre = ""

        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = input("enter each element of the matrix: ").split()
        m1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]

        for i in m1:
            if count == 1:
                pre = "st"
            elif count == 2:
                pre = "nd"
            elif count == 3:
                pre = "rd"
            else:
                pre = "th"

            while validInteger != True:
                if i.isdigit():
                    validInteger = True
                else:
                    s_count = str(count)

                    count = count - 1
                    m1[count] = input("enter a valid integer for the element in the "+s_count+pre+" place: ")
                    count = count + 1

            count = count + 1
            validInteger = False

        print(m1)
      
    matrix_maker()
```

Comment: You do not update the variable `i` in your while loop, so if `i.isdigit()` is false, there is no way for it to become true.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing when I assign a new input to m1[count]?  Because when I have i print out after the new input, it prints out the new input.  Or if I pint out the new list, the element reflects the new input.  Or if I check if (m1[count]).isdigit() it still doesn't work

Comment: You updated `m1[count]`, so `m1` changed, but at no point did you change `i`.

Comment: "if I check (m1[count]).isdigit() it still doesn't work" — Your code does not update `m1[count]`. It updates `m1[count-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

To help you down the path of learning to code, here are some comments:

1. Don't load data items into separate variables, this is why we have lists, strs, dicts, etc.
2. Don't use a counter, in python enumerate() iterates a counter if/when you need it. There is no need to carry a separate counter variable.
3. You should separate seemingly unrelated code to a different function.
4. Avoid while loop flags. In python this should be avoidable 99.9% of the time. A while statement should contain only the logic needed to keep the while statement going.

Updated Code:

```
def digit2str(digit):
    if digit in [1,2,3]:
        pre = ['st','nd','rd'][digit-1]
    else:
        pre = 'th'
    return str(digit)+pre

def matrix_maker():
    data = input("enter each element of the matrix: ").split()
    for n,element in enumerate(data):
        while not data[n].isdigit():
            data[n] = input("enter a valid integer for the element in the "+digit2str(n+1)+" place: ")
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code. In your code piece, I have changed "if i.isdigit():" line to "if m1[count-1].isdigit():" because you want to update your condition with new input. So, it will be more appropriate for your case.

```
def matrix_maker():
    count = 1
    validInteger = False
    pre = ""

    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = input("enter each element of the matrix: ").split()
    m1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]

    for i in m1:
        if count == 1:
            pre = "st"
        elif count == 2:
            pre = "nd"
        elif count == 3:
            pre = "rd"
        else:
            pre = "th"

        while validInteger != True:
            if m1[count-1].isdigit():
                validInteger = True
            else:
                s_count = str(count)
                count = count - 1
                m1[count] = input("enter a valid integer for the element in the "+s_count+pre+" place: ")
                count = count + 1
        count = count + 1
        validInteger = False
    print(m1)

matrix_maker()
```